# Form Characters not displayed correctly at runtime - VS Code PowerShell

Tags: winforms, powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm making a forms application with powershell. I'm having issues getting the characters "æ", "ø", "å" to be displayed correctly in a label. See the screengrab below for how they appear. There seems to be some type of encoding issue and since Powershell holds the characters as utf-16 in memory, I'm guessing the issue is with the `System.Windows.Forms.Label` I'm using.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Width = 800
$Form.Height = 500
$Form.BackColor = "#dff3ee" #"#00554b"
$Form.AutoSize = $false
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Info= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Info.Width = 250
$Info.Height = 70
$Info.AutoSize = $false
$Info.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,20)
$Info.Font = "Arial Unicode MS, 9"
$Info.Text = "Why is this æ ø å displayed wrong"
$Form.Controls.AddRange(@($Info))
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

`$PSVersionTable`

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.145
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

[image: Screengrab wrong formatting]

I'm not able to fix the issue. But I'm packing this in a .exe with PS2EXE and then the characters are displayed correctly. Since it is correct in prod I'm not gonna bother anymore with this.

Comment: Make sure you have saved the  powershell file in Unicode format.

Comment: It is saved as UTF-8

Comment: So just share a [MCVE].

Comment: Works as expected for me. See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnwKx.png). I just copied your code and pasted in Windows PowerShell ISE and run it.

Comment: What sorcery is this...In ISE it shows as expected for me too.

Comment: Even in Windows PowerShell console, if I run `.\MCVE.ps1` it works well. Please edit your question and share reproduction steps.

Comment: Just to add, when testing I'm seeing no issues https://i.gyazo.com/6df9acd735ec33952d32120656c634f9.png

Comment: I saved the snippet above in a file and ran from Powershell terminal. The text is then displayed wrong. Could it be something with my terminal environment?

Comment: I see that the $OutputEncoding is set to ASCIIEncoding. I'm going to try to change that

Comment: any luck with the changes?

Comment: Nope, not yet. Any advice?

Comment: what version of PS are you using? for reference i'm using: PSVersion                      5.1.16299.1004

Comment: Added PSVersionTable to question. But the weird thing is that ISE and terminal+VSCode shows the characters differently even the PSVersion is the same

Comment: @Starlord I see you said it's packaging correctly, a very bizarre issue.

Comment: It's really annoying, Both ISE and VSCode is running the script with the same PSVersion.

Comment: Try to add [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() on topp of your script.

Answer (score 1):

When I paste the code in **Windows PowerShell ISE** and I save it, it works as expected but when I paste it in **VS CODE** and save it, then at run-time it does't show those characters correctly.

It depends to the tools which saves the file. If you use *Windows PowerShell ISE*, it saves the file with `UTF-8 With BOM` (Or *UTF-8 with Signature*) but when you use *VS CODE*, the default setting is saving the file with `UTF-8` (or *UTF-8 without BOM*, or *UTF-8 without Signature*).

So the difference is in the file encoding, or to be more precise, having or not having [BOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/byte-order-mark?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

To fix the problem in VS CODE:

- Open VS CODE
- At the right side of the status bar, click on encoding. (It should be *UTF-8* by default)
- In the menu which opens at top, choose *Save with Encoding*
- From the next menu, choose, *UTF-8 with BOM*

Comment: Use notepad++ and change the format using the encoding type. I found it as the easiest one to tackle this issue.

Comment: @RanadipDutta Not just NP++, any text editor with this feature, including MS Word, VS or VS CODE as well. However if you use PowerShell ISE, you don't need to to anything, it will save with BOM. But if you are using VS Code  changing the settings in VS CODE is much better and much easier, because you don't need to change the encoding for each file.